# How to use getHeaderContribution() in wicket 6.x or 7.x?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I have code like below,

```
add(CssPackageResource.getHeaderContribution("css/$/styles.css?v=1.1".replace("$", reqLocale)));
```

I am trying to upgrade it into 6.x , but am unable to use getHeaderContribution() method,

Can you suggest me how can I change above code?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)` of your page/component and insert the following code there:

```
response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new CssResourceReference(YourWebPage.class, String.format("css/%s/styles.css?v=1.1", reqLocale))));
```

The css file path should then be relative to `YourWebPage`.

Detailed migration path can be found here in the Wiki pages.

Step 1:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5#MigrationtoWicket1.5-HeaderContribution

Step 2:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+6.0#MigrationtoWicket6.0-IHeaderResponse,includingdecoratorsandfilters

Comment: Hi user5474918, do you have any solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963393/deployed-web-application-jdk-1-6-wicket-1-4-9-in-jboss-eap-7-0-getting-wicke?noredirect=1#comment77115679_44963393